# how to disable Delete `⏎`eslintprettier/prettier

Tags: newline, eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint

I'm using eslint + prettier + typescript-eslint

I added this rule

```
    "padded-blocks":[2,{ "blocks": "always","classes":"always" ,"switches":"always" }],
```

wanted to add newline

but prettier/prettier  complain  `` Delete `⏎`eslintprettier/prettier ``

how to disable this complain (only this complain as I want prettier/prettier do anot## er job)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prettier is all or nothing, it’s aim is to stop your team arguing over things like this.

I think most people have something in Prettier that they don’t like, but accept it because the overall benefit is greater than the minor annoyances.